# search.php file not pointing where it should

Tags: theme-development

Hi I have I started to create my first wordpress template yesterday and today I have gotten to  the point where I have to create the search page result.From what I found online that should be search.php file.But for some reason it seems Wordpress is not pointing to that page when I try to search.I also created the searchform.php.Here is my code for it:

```
    <form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
        <input type="text" value="type your search"/>     
    </form>
```

What am I doing wrong?Do I have to activate the search page in functions.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That input needs a `name` attribute of `s`:

```
<input type="text" name="s" value="type your search" />
```